# Getting value by incrementing to a specific row in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, copy-paste, excel-2019

So I have a long list of raw data in Excel wherein I need a formula to get the values of specific rows and paste them into another column. This is how I want it to happen.

Picture of the Data in my Excel file:

[image: Raw Data I have in Excel]

I need the end result to be like this:

[image: End Result]

Is there any formula for this?

Comment: If each address block is always 4 rows, and there are two empty rows between each block, you could use INDEX and some math.

Comment: I need something like when I start at row A1 and go to A5, it will increment by 4 and so on. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly the answer to your question, but if you have at least 1 of your data sets to use as an input value, you can `match()` your data into a table... a little bit closer to what I think you're asking.

---

You can achieve this with a combination of `Match()`, `Address()`, and `Indirect`.

[image]

I input the red value (in the image, "headerB") and I can output the subsequent values in `D15` with this formula:

```
=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(MATCH(C15,A1:A10)+1,1))
```

I match find the input value in column A using `Match()`.

Then, I use that to get an address of a cell by offsetting `+1` in the `row` argument of `Address()`.  The output would be `$A$7` in this case... i get the value of that address using `Indirect()`, so you will see `b1`.

For the other subvalues, you can change your offset within the row argument of `Address()` to be `+2` and `+3`.

---

**Edit:**

Similar to the above, you could use some helper columns and get your data without needing to have a starting value:

```
=INDEX(A1,0) 'outputs headerA in the image example
```

You can drag that formula across as needed... or you can do something like:

[image]

This uses helper values in the formula:

```
=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(C$13+$G15,1))
```

Note that the 1, 6, 11, will allow you to select the range and "drag" down to get the offset since they're always the same spaced distance.

Comment: If I'm going to put that in my spreadsheet, what would be their corresponding values?

Comment: @Abraham what do you mean?  These give you the concept to resolve the issue.  You have 4 cells of data, so I made a mock-up of a relateable scale.

Comment: What would it look like if you put my values into your spreadsheet? Just so that I can know what goes to where. By the way, thanks for the answer. Big help!

Comment: @Abraham `headerA` = `18 maple ave`, `a1` = `waldwick, nj 07463`, `a2` = `$2,300`, and `a3` = `862.281.6276`.   Looks like you'll need to combine headerA and a1 to get your full address.

Comment: Maybe merge and center will do the trick there but if there is any other easier way for me to do that, kindly let me know.

Comment: @Abraham you could merge or use `&` to combine multiple indrect/address functions into a single-string ouput.  Good luck!

Comment: Can I ask for the file that you worked this on with? Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, I meant a step-by-step video on how you did this.